# Robolectric working with Intellij (Non-Android)

Tags: intellij-idea, robolectric

Hey I am trying to get robolectric (not in an Android app) to run on my machine using Intellij 14CE so that I can submit some PR's. Everything is passing via the command line when I run the two scripts provided in the README. But when I import the project in Injtellij and click `robolectric -> src -> test -> java` then run all tests. It fails with the error `Error:Android Source Generator: [robolectric] Android SDK is not specified`. I have modified my Project SDK to be Android 5.0.1, using Java 1.8. I have been messing around with the Modules and dependencies with no luck.

Anyone have tips about how to get it working.

Screenshots:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hard to say. Put your screenshots

Comment: @EugenMartynov I just added some, let me know if there is another screen you would find relevant.

Comment: I would ask question on robolectric github page. I've tried to repro and stuck on completely different place and error. Most probably because I have defined ANDROID_HOME

Comment: OK thanks. I have it defined as well

Comment: Any luck with solving this?